# Firebase and Unity Login System

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

Im completly new to Firebase. But since I want to make my Game online some people told me that Firebase is usefull to make online Databases.

I want to make a Register and Login System for my App.
Can anyone send me a link to an explanation or Tutorial on how to do Systems like that?

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: That said: have a look at the [documentation for Firebase Authentication for Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start).